# Create Bookmark in java using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to create a Bookmark in `docx file` using `docx4j api` in `java`. bookmark should start at first line of document and end at list line of document.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/BookmarkAdd.java and if you get stuck amend your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer and created bookmark successfully in docx file using below code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.wml.CTBookmark;
import org.docx4j.wml.CTMarkupRange;
import org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory;
import org.docx4j.wml.P;
import org.docx4j.wml.P.Hyperlink;
import org.docx4j.wml.R;


public class BookmarkAdd  extends AbstractSample {

    public static JAXBContext context = org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.jc; 

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        String outputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + "/OUT_bookmarkAdd.docx";;     

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("x");
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("x");
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("hello world");
        P p = (P)wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().get(2);
        R r = (R)p.getContent().get(0);

        String bookmarkName = "abcd"; 
        bookmarkRun(p,r, bookmarkName, 123);

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("x");
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("x");

        // Now add an internal hyperlink to it
        Hyperlink h = MainDocumentPart.hyperlinkToBookmark(bookmarkName, "link to bookmark");
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("some text").getContent().add(h);

        System.out.println( XmlUtils.marshaltoString(p, true)  );

        SaveToZipFile saver = new SaveToZipFile(wordMLPackage);
        saver.save(outputfilepath);
    }


    /**
     * Surround the specified r in the specified p
     * with a bookmark (with specified name and id)
     * @param p
     * @param r
     * @param name
     * @param id
     */
    public static void bookmarkRun(P p, R r, String name, int id) {

        // Find the index
        int index = p.getContent().indexOf(r);

        if (index<0) {
            System.out.println("P does not contain R!");
            return;
        }

        ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
        BigInteger ID = BigInteger.valueOf(id);


        // Add bookmark end first
        CTMarkupRange mr = factory.createCTMarkupRange();
        mr.setId(ID);
        JAXBElement<CTMarkupRange> bmEnd = factory.createBodyBookmarkEnd(mr);
        p.getContent().add(index+1, bmEnd); 

        // Next, bookmark start
        CTBookmark bm = factory.createCTBookmark();
        bm.setId(ID);
        bm.setName(name);       
        JAXBElement<CTBookmark> bmStart =  factory.createBodyBookmarkStart(bm);
        p.getContent().add(index, bmStart);

    }

}
```